# question related to app_controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to include a small code in each page of my site.
Is there any way to do this without modifying each controller?

For example - I want to read/unread message from `Message` model.

Can i do this using the app_controller? I have add following function in app_controller.php.
I need suggestion. Please help me.

```
function messageStatus() {
    App::import('Model','Message');
    $new_message = $this->Message->find(
    'first',
            array (
                'conditions' => array (
                    'Message.status' => '1'
                )
            )
        );
    $this->set("new_message",$new_message); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on when you want to execute your actions, you will have to override in the `app_controller.php` file one of the following functions ([according to the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks)), :

```
beforeFilter()
afterFilter()
beforeRender()
```

Since all your other controllers will be inheriting the methods of this class, your actions will be executed every time (as specified in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks)) one of your controllers are executed.

If you want to have a controller that does not run the code in the `app_controller` simply override the method again locally.

Answer (score 0):

As user559744 mentioned you can use AppController within your application to create attributes and methods that can be accessed by your controllers. AppController is the parent class of your controllers.

You should copy app_controller.php from /cake/libs/controller/ to YOURAPP/app_controller.php to avoid making changes to the core files.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/957/The-App-Controller